# Why this c++ program giving seg fault

Tags: c++

Why this program giving segmentation fault. I am allocating the memory for 20 strings. (by default is also 20). and setting and trying to access 20th element.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class myarray
{
  private:
    string *items;
  public:

    myarray (int size=20)
    {
      items = new string[size];
    }

    ~myarray()
    {
      delete items;
    }

    string& operator[] (const int index)
    {
      return items[index];
    }
    /* 
    void setvalue (int index, string value)
    {
      items[index] = value;
    }

    string getvalue (int index)
    { 
      return items[index];
    }
    */

};


int main()
{
  myarray m1(20);
  myarray m2;
  m1[19] = "test ion";
  cout << m1[19];
  //m1.setvalue (2, "Devesh ");
  //m1.setvalue (8, "Vivek ");
  //cout << m1.getvalue(19);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try running it in a debugger such as `gdb`. That will allow you to print a stack trace of the segfault.

Comment: Also, rather than new[] and delete[], I would use an std::vector<std::string> or at least an std::unique_ptr<string[]>.

Comment: What you're doing here looks **very** similar (albeit not *exactly* the same) to `std::map`. Is there any reason you're not just using that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you allocate an array like you are doing with `new string[size]` you need to use `delete[] items;`

Answer (score 3):

Use `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

Rule of thumb is:

- If you have allocated memory with `new`, free it with `delete`.
- If you have allocated memory with `new[]`, free it with `delete[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Change constructor to:

```
items = new string[size]();
```

And destructor to:

```
delete[] items;
```